# Fetching(GET) image url with applied image styles using jsonapi module

Tags: javascript, ajax, media, 8

Looking to make request using the jsonapi module to GET all urls that point to the images optimized version of the image.

If I use the Drupal front-end with Twig and view my page and inspect the images on the page I get something like this

`http://local.mysite.com/sites/default/files/styles/promo_background_image/public/promo-backgrounds/MYIMAGE.png?h=df23a951&itok=fslZ-kmD`

If I make a request to my api endpoint and drill down to the image field it does not have the included image style url.
```

```
{
"data": {
    "type": "file--file",
    "id": "b74b73fb-19fd-48a2-ac91-8a7aacd7fe18",
    "attributes": {
        "fid": 2,
        "uuid": "b74b73fb-19fd-48a2-ac91-8a7aacd7fe18",
        "langcode": "en",
        "filename": "MYIMAGE.png",
        "uri": "public://promo-backgrounds/MYIMAGE.png",
        "filemime": "image/png",
        "filesize": 37624,
        "status": true,
        "created": 1508723420,
        "changed": 1508723610,
        "url": "/sites/default/files/promo-backgrounds/MYIMAGE.png"
    },
    "relationships": {
        "uid": {
            "data": {
                "type": "user--user",
                "id": "b044b880-ab4e-495b-b2d1-6a4fe58dc609"
            },
            "links": {
                "self": "http://local.mysite.com/api/file/file/b74b73fb-19fd-48a2-ac91-8a7aacd7fe18/relationships/uid?language=en",
                "related": "http://local.mysite.com/api/file/file/b74b73fb-19fd-48a2-ac91-8a7aacd7fe18/uid?language=en"
            }
        }
    },
    "links": {
        "self": "http://local.mysite.com/api/file/file/b74b73fb-19fd-48a2-ac91-8a7aacd7fe18?language=en"
    }
},
"links": {
    "self": "http://local.mysite.com/api/file/file/b74b73fb-19fd-48a2-ac91-8a7aacd7fe18?language=en"
}
```

}

```

How can one get access the image style uri using the jsonapi as my api server?

Comment: What is the exact answer? Please post

Answer (score 1):

I would do it

create file: test_api.info.yml

```
name: Test API
type: module
description: Custom RESTful API module with GET/POST/PUT/DELETE etc.. method examples.
author: Minnur Yunusov
core: 8.x
```

create file: test_api.routing.yml

```
test_api.getparameter:
  path: 'my-api/get/{nid}'
  defaults: { _controller: '\Drupal\test_api\Controller\TestAPIController::getpara_example' }
  methods:  [GET]
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

create file: /src/Controller/TestAPIController.php

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\test_api\Controller\TestAPIController.
 */

namespace Drupal\test_api\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

/**
 * Controller routines for test_api routes.
 */
class TestAPIController extends ControllerBase {



  /**
   * Callback for `my-api/get.json` API method.
   */
  public function getpara_example($nid, Request $request ) {

    //get node;
    $node=node_load($nid);

    //get image uri
    $image =$node->field_image->entity->getFileUri();

    $style = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('image_style')->load('thumbnail');

    $url = $style->buildUrl($image);


    $response['nid'] = $nid;
    $response['uri'] = file_create_url($image);
    $response['image_original'] = file_create_url($image);
    $response['image_style_thumbnail'] =file_create_url($url);


    return new JsonResponse( $response );
  }




}
```

test:
url: localhost/drupal8/my-api/get/30
method: get

note: 30 is nid.

result:

```
{
  "nid": "30",
  "uri": "public://2017-10/generateImage_1RwT72.png",
  "image_original": "http://jeremiselxi.260mb.net/drupal8/sites/default/files/2017-10/generateImage_1RwT72.png",
  "image_style_thumbnail": "http://jeremiselxi.260mb.net/drupal8/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/2017-10/generateImage_1RwT72.png?itok=Dzg02oew"
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. Shortly after I posted this I found a module that addresses this issue. https://www.drupal.org/project/consumer_image_styles

I hope this helps others looking for a solution.

Comment: Where should I create those files? Please tell us clearly

Comment: these files must be created inside the / modules / test_api folder.